# Android Activity: Access methods of a model

Tags: java, android

Sorry for this generic title, but I couldnt find a better formulation.
I included the library [Swipeable-Cards](https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards) in my android project.
In MyActvitiy.java the oncreate method includes something like that:

```
    mCardContainer = (CardContainer) findViewById(R.id.layoutview);

    SimpleCardStackAdapter adapter = new SimpleCardStackAdapter(this);

    adapter.add(new CardModel("Title2", "Description2 goes here", r.getDrawable(R.drawable.picture2)));
    adapter.add(new CardModel("Title3", "Description3 goes here", r.getDrawable(R.drawable.picture3)));

    CardModel cardModel = new CardModel("Title1", "Description goes here", r.getDrawable(R.drawable.picture1));

    cardModel.setOnCardDimissedListener(new CardModel.OnCardDimissedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLike() {
            Log.i("Swipeable Cards","I like the card ");
        }
    });

    adapter.add(cardModel);

    mCardContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to be able to log the title of the object on onLike(), too. However, I don't know how to access it.

Pseudo-Code:

```
cardModel.setOnCardDimissedListener(new CardModel.OnCardDimissedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLike() {
        Log.i("Swipeable Cards","I like the card with the title: " + this.getTitle());
        // should show Title1, Title2, Title3 after 3 swipes.
    }
});
```

The CardModel class already contains the method getTitle(), I just don't know how to access it!

```
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you gonna have to sub-class this `OnCardDimissedListener` and pass the parameter to it, something like that:

```
public class MyOnCardDimissedListener implements OnCardDimissedListener{

    private String title;

    public MyOnCardDimissedListener(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLike() {
        Log.i("Swipeable Cards", title);
    }
}
```

then you use it like that:

```
cardModel.setOnCardDimissedListener(new MyOnCardDimissedListener(cardModel.getTitle()));
```

there you go... each instance of `MyOnCardDimissedListener` have a reference to the title. It's a bit wasteful on my opinion, but the other way would be to edit the library source code to pass the `CardModel` object on its listener.

Comment: Thank you. But the title is now always "Title1". I guess I have to access the title through the adapter object?

Comment: It doesn't matter what's the value of the string `title` you pass it from the card model during the listener construction and the listener will use that value. Read more carefully and understand the code I posted because I'm pretty sure it's the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the most basic rules in Object Oriented Programming
Create a CardModel Object and call this object's method.

```
    CardModel cardModel = new CardModel(...);
    cardModel.getTitle();
```

that's it!